# Adding MMYYYY to save name on a Variant

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that splits worksheets into new workbooks and saves them by the name in column B. 
What I want to do is add "ABC *MM_YYYY*" to the end of the file name when it saves each file.

I know I should be inserting a line similar to this when setting fileNm:

```
Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "mm_yyyy")
```

I tried

```
fileNm = Dir(loopFolder & "*ABC " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "mm_yyyy") & ".xlsx")

fileNm = Dir(loopFolder & "ABC " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "mm_yyyy") & "*.xlsx")
```

with no luck. If someone can guide me to getting this fixed, that would be awesome.

```
Dim loopFolder As String
Dim fileNm As Variant
Dim myFiles As New Collection

loopFolder = "J:\Documents\Hookset\"
fileNm = Dir(loopFolder & "*.xlsx")

Do While fileNm <> ""
    myFiles.Add fileNm
    fileNm = Dir
Loop
```

*edit - I was looking at the wrong part of the code and the date insert should have been in here, rather than above

'''    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim FolderName As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
FolderName = xWb.Path & "\Hookset\" 
For Each xWs In xWb.Worksheets
    xWs.Copy
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        Select Case xWb.FileFormat
            Case 51:
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If Application.ActiveWorkbook.HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56:
                FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else:
                FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
    End If

    xFile = FolderName & "\" & Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & " ABC " & Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1), "mm_yyyy") & FileExtStr
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFile, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
Next
```

'''

I was missing from xFile and now runs well.

Comment: Is the filename ending in MMYYY a new name? If so, why are you using it within `Dir`, which looks for an existing file?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but `"ABC" & chr(32) & format(now,"mm-yyyy")` maybe?

Comment: @BigBen as simple as your question was, it made me look at the right section of my code. Thanks

Comment: So do you have an issue still, or is your problem resolved?

Comment: it is resolved.